# Not able to create collection in solrcloud mode

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have installed solr on 3 node. I wanted to create collection with 3 shards and 2 replica. But I am getting following error.

I have stared solr with following command

**bin/solr start -c -z xk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 -Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs -Dsolr.hdfs.home=hdfs:///user/solr**

My solr is started.

I am creating collection with following command

**bin/solr  create -c Collection1 -d data_driven_schema_configs -n wafmaster1944  -rf 2 -s 3**

But I am getting following error

Collection: Collection1 operation: create failed:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.createCollection(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:2070)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.processMessage(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:219)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerTaskProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerTaskProcessor.java:433)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nodeName does not contain expected '_' seperator: :8983
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.getBaseUrlForNodeName(ZkStateReader.java:780)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.createCollection(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:2007)

Please help me to solve this issue.

Vikas

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nodeName does not contain expected '_' seperator: :8983 at

Solr node names usually have the format as 10.0.0.0:8983_solr , you can see this under zookeeper /livenodes , it seems the bin/create is not identifying/sending right node name , instead of bin/solr , can you try using solr rest api where you have option to specify the node name as well

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-create

What version of solr are you using ?

Comment: Hi Avinash, I am using solr 5.5 version.. I wanted one more thing .. when I am creating collection with 3 shards and one replica . I am able to create it successfully.

Comment: Hi Avinash, Thanks now I am getting above issue . Now I am getting error Unable to create core [wafmaster1805_shard1_replica2] Caused by: Java heap space. I have tried with adding SOLR_HEAP="1024m" in solr.in.sh file and also tried with starting solr with passing argument -m 1g.

Comment: Also I have set <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation">false</bool> in my solrconfig.xml file